# CefSharp The user agent does not support public key credentials

Tags: javascript, c#, веб-программирование, cefsharp

При попытке отправки формы с логином и паролем через `CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser` возникает следующая ошибка:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user agent does not support
> public key credentials.

Часть скрипта сайта, в которой происходит ошибка:

```
Pl = function(e) {
    var t = e.response, r = e.data, n = e.dispatch;
    if (t.userInfo && On(vl(vl({}, t.userInfo), {}, {login: r.login}), fe), window.PasswordCredential) {

        var o = new window.PasswordCredential({
                    id: r.login,
            password: r.password
        });

        navigator.credentials.store(o).then((function() { qr(), wo(n, r, t) })) <-- error here
    }
    else wo(n, r, t)
};
```

Пробовал изменить стандартное значение `UserAgent`, но это не помогло.

```
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36";
```

---

Я попробовал загрузить следующий сайт, где предоставляется информацию о браузере, который я использую: [www.whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). Результат загрузки и заголовки запроса в DevTools прикрепляю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [тут можно посмотреть поддержку агентов](https://caniuse.com/?search=webauthn) и [тут вроде как пример проверки на поддержку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939695/occasional-notsupportederror-exception-using-webauthn), может пригодится)

Comment: Я взял значение поля `UserAgent` из своего браузера Chrome, где не возникает подобных проблем. Я думаю проблема не в значении поля `UserAgent`.

Comment: Я не знаком конкретно с CerfSharp, но в общей практике меняются заголовки user-agent для запросов,  но по факту не меняется обработчик ответов. Как использовался Chromium при запросе(что бы вы не писали в заголовках), так он и используется при обработке ответа

Comment: @Alexandr Мне кажется что UserAgent всё таки меняется как положено. Посмотрите моё дополнение к вопросу.

Comment: Есть ещё заголовок `sec-ch-ua`. Он может влиять в данном случае на результат?

Comment: дело тут не в заголовках, вам пишут "ваш браузер не поддерживает public key credentials"

Comment: судя по всему, CEF просто не поддерживает хранение кредов ни в каком виде (https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=17293), и падает при попытке работать с navigator.credentials. Ошибка чисто клиенская, это сам браузер вам пишет, что вызов не поддерживается - просто сообщение левое.

Comment: @D.Stark , так вы  туда ж подставляете эти заголовки, это вы говорите этому сайту кто вы, то что вы скажете, то он и отвечает, он не может сам проверить эту инфу никак

Comment: @Alexandr Ну так никакой сайт же не может это проверить. Почему же тогда возникает ошибка. Кажется PashaPash что то знает.

Comment: @PashaPash Как можно исправить эту проблему? Может есть какие то расширения на CEF или другие подобные проекты аналогичного уровня, которые поддерживают public key credentials.

Comment: [Вот пример с заголовками](https://ibb.co/4gHV20N), можно написать что угодно. Да, согласен с @PashaPash это вполне вероятно, что сам браузер кидай в консоль ошибку

Comment: @D.Stark я не настолько крут в embedded браузерах. тут из вариантов - или убирать этот код (если возможно), или подсовывать что-то до загрузки скриптов, что застабает navigator.credentials.store, или window.PasswordCredential выставить с null (тогда скорее всего if пропустит - это явно проверка на поддержку фичи со стороны браузера)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связана не с заголовком `UserAgent`, а с поддержкой в CEF Credential Management API. Сообщение об ошибке выводилось самим браузером при вызове метода `navigator.credentials.store`. Выполнение следующего скрипта решило мою проблему:

```
navigator.credentials.store = function (Credential) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); }); };
```